# Chrome Extension That Opens New Tab & Simulate a ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am learning to building a relatively simple Chrome extension and I'm at a point where I've got a `background.js` file with this set of code.

> chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
>      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
>          chrome.tabs.create( { url: "https://hello.world.com/" } );
>      });
>   });

Upon button press of the extension, it's supposed to launch a new Chrome tab with https://hello.world.com.

There is a specific AngularJS button on `https//hello.world.com` called `ng-click="aaa.bbb()"` that I would like to trigger as part of the same process (when the new Chrome tab is launching `http://hello.world.com`), but I'm not sure what lines I need to add to the my `background.js` file to trigger that action.

Appreciate anyone's help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change ng-click="aaa.bbb()" to ng-click="bbb()"

Comment: @RameshRajendran where do I put this in the my `background.js` file? What would that line of code look like?

Comment: Do you mean button click event on angularjs?

Comment: I think so. Sorry, I don't really know much about the javascript that's going on. The web is supposedly coded with Angular. And that button click - when I go "inspect element" - shows something like `ng-click="aaa.bbb()"`. I'm not sure how to trigger it though in my basic `background.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare content_script and execute it in the URL of the tab to open.
However, since the trigger of content_script is sandbox, it cannot be triggered directly.
Therefore, from content_script
It finally works by adding a script element containing the code to target.click (); to document.body.